# How to call specific Json Objects while search in all data accordingly using js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

Can anyone help me implement this JS code with my JSON file? I was looking through this javascript code to implement on my parsed JSON code but all the time it was confusing and irritating task to call specific EnrollmentNumber from search, validating it and then displaying the Enrollment Number Name of Person Marks.Name and Marks.External on the table as mentioned in js file.

I tried defining var but again and again, the code does not execute properly

```js
var allData = []
var singleResult = {}
var activationList = {}
var regNo;

$('#registration-number').keypress("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
     calculate();
    }
})

$("#calculate-button").click(function(){
 calculate();
});

var calculate = () => {
 regNo = $("#registration-number").val();

 if(regNo != "non"){

  getResult(regNo)
  .then(() => {
   return updateTable(regNo);
  })
  .then(() => {
   return calculateGpa(regNo);
  }) 
  // here add ageregate also
  .then((gpa) => {
   $("#show-gpa").html('GPA : ' + gpa);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
   alert('Registration number not found');
  })

 }else{
  alert('Please fill the form')
 }
}

// Fetch result from json file
var getResult = (regNo) => {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // Show loader
  $('.loader').css('display', 'flex');
  $.getJSON('results/33.json')
  .then((res) => {
   allData = res;
   singleResult = allData.EnrollmentNumber[regNo];
   createActivationList();
   return resolve();
  })
  .catch((err) => {
   return reject(err);
  })
  .then(() => {
   // Remove loader
   $('.loader').css('display', 'none');
  })
 });
}


// Initialize all subject activations to true
var createActivationList = () => {
 activationList = {};
 var result = singleResult;
 var subs = Object.keys(result);
 for(var i=0;i<subs.length;i++){
  activationList[subs[i]] = true;
 }
}

// Update result table
var updateTable = (regNo) => {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  markup = '';
  if(!singleResult)
   return reject('Registration number not found');
  subs = Object.keys(singleResult);
  createMarkup(markup, singleResult, subs, 0)
  .then((markup) => {
   // Clear table
   $('#subject-table tbody').html('');
   // Update table
   $('#subject-table tbody').append(markup);
   // Show table
   $('#result').show();
   return resolve();
  })
  .catch((err) => {
   return reject(err);
  });

 });
}


// Create markup of rows
var createMarkup = (markup, result, subs, counter) => {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if(counter < subs.length){
   var subjectId = subs[counter];
   var subjectGrade = result[subs[counter]];
   var subjectName = allData['Marks'][subs[counter]]['Name'];
   markup += `<tr>
     <td>
      <label class="checkbox-container">
       <input type="checkbox" checked="true" id="${subjectId}" onchange="toggleActivation('${subjectId}')">
       <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
     </td>
     <td>
                        <div class="subject-title">${subjectName}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="subject-grade">${subjectGrade}</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>`;
   return resolve(createMarkup(markup, result, subs, counter+1))
  }else{
   return resolve(markup);
  }
 });
}

// Calculate GPA
var calculateGpa = (regNo) => {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  var result = singleResult;
  var subs = Object.keys(result);
  var totalCredit = 0.0;
  var pointSum = 0.0;
  for(var i=0; i<subs.length; i++){
   if(activationList[subs[i]]){

   var subjectGrade = result[subs[i]];
   var subjectCredit = allData['Marks'][subs[i]]['Credits'];
   pointSum += (gradeToPoint(subjectGrade) * subjectCredit);
   totalCredit += subjectCredit;
   }
  }
  var gpa = pointSum / totalCredit
  gpa = Math.round((gpa) * 100) / 100
  return resolve(gpa);
 });
}

// Convert grade to point
var gradeToPoint = (grade) => {
 if(grade >= '90')
  return 10;
 else if(grade >= '75')
  return 9;
 else if(grade >= '65')
  return 8;
 else if(grade >= '55')
  return 7;
 else if(grade >= '50')
  return 6;
 else if(grade >= '45')
  return 5;
 else if(grade >= '40')
  return 4;
 else
  return 0;
}

var goBack = () => {
    window.history.back();
}
```

```css
This is my JSON file format
{
    "Semester": "07",
    "Programme": "BACHELOR OF TECHNOLOGY (ELECTRICAL & ELECTRONICS ENGINEERING)",
    "Batch": "2015",
    "Examination": "REGULAR December, 2018",
    "Institution": "BHARATI VIDYAPEETH COLLEGE OF ENGINEERING",
    "CollegeCode": "115",
    "EnrollmentNumber": "00211504915",
    "Name": "ABHISHEK",
    "Marks": [
      {
        "Id": "49401",
        "Credits": "4",
        "Internal": "16",
        "External": "67",
        "Total": 83,
        "Grade": "A+",
        "Name": "ELECTRICAL DRIVES"
      },
      {
        "Id": "49403",
        "Credits": "4",
        "Internal": "18",
        "External": "60",
        "Total": 78,
        "Grade": "A+",
        "Name": "ADVANCED CONTROL SYSTEMS"
      },
      {
        "Id": "49405",
        "Credits": "3",
        "Internal": "18",
        "External": "56",
        "Total": 74,
        "Grade": "A",
        "Name": "EHV AC AND HVDC TRANSMISSIONS"
      }
    ],
    "CreditsSecured": "25",
    "_id": "5cd3d6ae390a7a20c80b75f7"
  },
  {
    "Semester": "07",
    "Programme": "BACHELOR OF TECHNOLOGY (ELECTRICAL & ELECTRONICS ENGINEERING)",
    "Batch": "2015",
    "Examination": "REGULAR December, 2018",
    "Institution": "BHARATI VIDYAPEETH COLLEGE OF ENGINEERING",
    "CollegeCode": "115",
    "EnrollmentNumber": "00411504915",
    "Name": "AKHIL KHANDELWAL",
    "Marks": [
      {
        "Id": "49401",
        "Credits": "4",
        "Internal": "19",
        "External": "59",
        "Total": 78,
        "Grade": "A+",
        "Name": "ELECTRICAL DRIVES"
      },
      {
        "Id": "49403",
        "Credits": "4",
        "Internal": "18",
        "External": "56",
        "Total": 74,
        "Grade": "A",
        "Name": "ADVANCED CONTROL SYSTEMS"
      }
    ],
    "CreditsSecured": "25",
    "_id": "5cd3d6ae390a7a20c80b75f8"
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="GPA">
    <meta name="keywords" content="calculator">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#3F6AE6">
    <title>GPA Calculator</title>
    <link rel="icon" sizes="512x512" href="img/calculator.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="css/mont.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/viewer.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- LOADER -->
    <div class="loader"><img src="img/loader.gif" class="img-loader"></div>
    <!-- SIDEBAR BUTTON -->
    <span onclick="goBack()" class="sidebar-button">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
    <!-- HEADER -->
    <div class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="header-message">
                    <h6><b>Viewer</b></h6>
                </div>
                <div class="offset-md-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 offset-sm-0 header-message-container">
                    <div class="header-message">
                        <input id="registration-number" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="number" placeholder="Registration number">
                    </div>
                    <div class="header-message">
                        <button id="calculate-button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">SUBMIT</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- CARDS -->
    <div class="container grade-container" id="result">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="offset-md-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 offset-sm-0">
    <div class="name" id="name">
                    </div>
                <div class="card shadow-sm">
    <div class="gpa-row" id="show-gpa">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <table id="subject-table" class="table table-striped">
                            <tbody></tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/viewer.js"></script>
 <script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-116549528-1');
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you specify where the bugg occurs specifically please

Answer (score 0):

you can use filter method of javascript;

```
const allData = [{
"Semester": "07",
"Programme": "BACHELOR OF TECHNOLOGY (ELECTRICAL & ELECTRONICS ENGINEERING)",
"Batch": "2015",
"Examination": "REGULAR December, 2018",
"Institution": "BHARATI VIDYAPEETH COLLEGE OF ENGINEERING",
"CollegeCode": "115",
"EnrollmentNumber": "00211504915",
"Name": "ABHISHEK",
"Marks": [
    {
        "Id": "49401",
        "Credits": "4",
        "Internal": "16",
        "External": "67",
        "Total": 83,
        "Grade": "A+",
        "Name": "ELECTRICAL DRIVES"
    },
    {
        "Id": "49403",
        "Credits": "4",
        "Internal": "18",
        "External": "60",
        "Total": 78,
        "Grade": "A+",
        "Name": "ADVANCED CONTROL SYSTEMS"
    },
    {
        "Id": "49405",
        "Credits": "3",
        "Internal": "18",
        "External": "56",
        "Total": 74,
        "Grade": "A",
        "Name": "EHV AC AND HVDC TRANSMISSIONS"
    }
],
"CreditsSecured": "25",
"_id": "5cd3d6ae390a7a20c80b75f7"
},
{
"Semester": "07",
"Programme": "BACHELOR OF TECHNOLOGY (ELECTRICAL & ELECTRONICS ENGINEERING)",
"Batch": "2015",
"Examination": "REGULAR December, 2018",
"Institution": "BHARATI VIDYAPEETH COLLEGE OF ENGINEERING",
"CollegeCode": "115",
"EnrollmentNumber": "00411504915",
"Name": "AKHIL KHANDELWAL",
"Marks": [
    {
        "Id": "49401",
        "Credits": "4",
        "Internal": "19",
        "External": "59",
        "Total": 78,
        "Grade": "A+",
        "Name": "ELECTRICAL DRIVES"
    },
    {
        "Id": "49403",
        "Credits": "4",
        "Internal": "18",
        "External": "56",
        "Total": 74,
        "Grade": "A",
        "Name": "ADVANCED CONTROL SYSTEMS"
    }
],
"CreditsSecured": "25",
"_id": "5cd3d6ae390a7a20c80b75f8"
}];

var getResult = (regNo) => {
let result = allData.filter(val => val.EnrollmentNumber == regNo); // allData json object array
return result;
}

console.log(getResult("00211504915"));
```

which json object you are provided i applied filter method and i get expected result. you can try as i mention. 
there is allData is an array of objects and we get one object at a time in value argument then compare with regno.